# How do you put data from one form as a default for another in the same view in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

Basically, I am new to Django. I am attempting to create a timesheet website where the user would select a task for the week and then add the hours they worked for each day that week.

However, each day is intended to be stored in an individual record. How would you create a form that would take only take one task input, but loop through and create 5 records, one for each day?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) since your question is primarily opinion based and to broad to answer properly.

Comment: show what you have tried.....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create multiple instances of the same model bound to form, use inline formsets. But these are not automatic, you have to define them in your code.

The most simplest way to create inline formsets with dynamic adding / removing of related model forms is to use `NestedModelAdmin`  with `NestedStackedInline` from django-nested-admin package:

https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin

Let's say there is Django Task model and Django Event model with many to one relationship to Task model:

```
from django.contrib import admin
import nested_admin

from .models import Event, Task

class EventInline(nested_admin.NestedStackedInline):
    model = Event

class TaskAdmin(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [EventInline]

admin.site.register(Task, TaskAdmin)
```

With such little code you will have powerful dynamic one to many model editor in django admin. But in such case users should have the access to django admin.

Otherwise, define formsets yourself and manage their addition / deletion yourself. There are many tutorials / pluggable modules for that.